# (Python) How to pass a variable from file1.py to file2.py in "REAL TIME"?

Tags: python

I have a question about how to pass a variable from `file1.py` to `file2.py`, which works in REAL TIME.

For example:

> file1.py

```
glob_val = 0

def cahange_val:
    global glob_val
    while True:
        global_val += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    change_val()
```

> file2.py

```
import file1
while True:
    print (file1.glob_val)
```

I run `file1.py` at first, and then run `file2.py`.

But I get the outputs always `0`. And then I change the `file2.py`

> file2_1.py

```
while True:
    import file1
    print (file1.glob_val)
```

also doesn't work.

Actually, file1 in my project is a GUI file (using pyqt5). The GUI file must read the output results from file2 every second and then show it in the GUI. When the passed variable not changes, that will be meaningless.

Comment: each process has it's own memory space, so what you're trying to do cannot work that way. Looks like you're looking for IPCs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: You are talking about Inter Process Communication, so called IPC. There are tons of ways to implement it, including pipes, shared memory, tcp, files and others. You can choose any of them based on your needs.

Comment: This is because once you run `file1.py`, the global variable is no longer in memory. When you do an `import file1` in `file2.py`, the function `cahange_val()` is not called and the global value remains 0. You could consider writing the value out to a file and then reading it in from the second file. This is still a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are evaluated at import time, if you change contents of a module after it has been imported, changes won't propagate. You need to `reload` that module to get updated contents. See [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html).

But, this is kinda strange idea for tracking a separate state (basically counter in your example), look into threading or 'Inter-process communication'. If you're on UNIX and do not want to deal with threading, you can mount chunk of memory to file system and write to it with one script and read from it with another, as a crude implementation of IPC.